# How to define a Vector to have all elements to be of the same type in Julia?

Tags: julia

I need to define a Vector such that all elements in it need to be of the same type, though the type itself can be of any type. I tried the below:

```
["1", 2] isa AbstractVector{T} where T <: Any
```

but this returns `true`.

The following works in this case and correctly returns `false` as needed:

```
["1", 2] isa AbstractVector{T} where T <: Union{AbstractString, Number}
```

But, I don't want to restrict the type to be only Strings, Numbers etc. So, how else can I restrict all elements of a Vector to be of the same type though the type itself can be flexible?

Comment: If you have a vector `v`, you can try `isconcretetype(eltype(v))`. Note that your question is a bit ambiguous, because all abstract types and Union types are still a "single type". In my response I assume that you actually mean a single, concrete type.

Comment: @DNF I would not like to manually check this using isconcretetype() but would like to know if there is a way I can declare it in the type definition itself for the Vector. This vector would be passed as an argument by the caller of my function, so I would like to specify the type expected for the vector in the function signature itself.

Comment: You're looking for a type signature that only admits vectors with concrete eltype?

Comment: Yes, for example [1, 2] or ["1", "2"] are acceptable inputs. But not ["1",  2]. Hope that is clear

Comment: I'm not aware of any way of doing that. But you can perform that check manually in your function body, without loss of performance, due to type specialization.

Answer (score 1):

`["2", 2]` is of type `Vector{Any}` and `T <: Any` is `true` because setting `T = Any` gives `Any <: Any` which should evaluate to `true`.

"1" is a `String` and `String <: AbstractString` is `true`. But Julia's type system only works like this

`T{S} <: T'{S}` is true if `T <: T'` but is not true if `T{S} <: T{S'}` even if `S <: S'`. I don't know the technical term for that in type theory but it should be detailed in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)